# Ptrace: IMG load detector

Tags: ptrace

How can I detect IMG load? Im trying to detect when the program is loaded into memory in order to put interrupts before each function. I'm trying to do something like PIN's IMG_AddInstrumentFunction.

I'm lost and I can't found info about it.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what r_brk is for. See include/link.h:

```
  struct r_debug
  {
    .....
    /* This is the address of a function internal to the run-time linker,
       that will always be called when the linker begins to map in a
       library or unmap it, and again when the mapping change is complete.
       The debugger can set a breakpoint at this address if it wants to
       notice shared object mapping changes.  */
    ElfW(Addr) r_brk;
    ....
   };
```

They even go on and explain how to find this value in the debugee:

```
/* This symbol refers to the "dynamic structure" in the `.dynamic' section
   of whatever module refers to `_DYNAMIC'.  So, to find its own
   `struct r_debug', a program could do:
     for (dyn = _DYNAMIC; dyn->d_tag != DT_NULL; ++dyn)
       if (dyn->d_tag == DT_DEBUG)
     r_debug = (struct r_debug *) dyn->d_un.d_ptr;
   */
```